# jQuery 3 - альтернатива функции live

Tags: jquery, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, раньше использовал функцию live или модуль livequery для доступа к загруженным с помощью AJAX элементам.

Нужно сделать что-то вроде:

```
$('img').livequery(function() {
    $(this).fancybox();
});
```

Как это сделать в jQuery 3.*?

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться `on`, например:

```
$('img').on('click',function() {
    $(this).fancybox();
});
```

Если необходимо реинициализировать `Fancybox` после `AJAX` запроса, просто вставьте вызов после окончания `AJAX` запроса (например)

```
......
'success' : function (data) {
    $('img').fancybox();
          }
```

Comment: Да, это работает, если нужно ловить нажатие, но, мне надо повесить, например, fancybox.

Comment: т.е без каких то действий активировать fancybox для картинки?